# Can someone explain to me why certain code I see has functions embedded within functions?

Tags: objective-c, ios, objective-c-blocks

For example I would see the following:

```
- (void) updateNotesView:(BOOL)visible animated:(BOOL)animated{

    void (^animations)(void) = ^{
        if (visible)
        {
            //do something
        }
        else
        {
            //do something
        }
     };


    void (^completion)(BOOL) = ^(BOOL finished){
        self.showingNotesView = visible;

        if (!visible)
        {
            //do something
        }
    };

}
```

I do not get the code that says :

```
void (^animations)(void)
```

or

```
void (^completion)(BOOL) = ^(BOOL finished)
```

can someone please explain?

Comment: They're [blocks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html). Basically a function wrapped in an object.

Comment: Blocks can be helpful in certain situations, usually ones that require an event to be triggered upon completion.  UIPrintInteractionController has a completion handler built into its delegate for example.  Or in animation chains, it can be used to trigger the next group or to just animate a single object.

Answer (score 1):

It's how you define a variable that will be a block or in some other cases function pointers like in c.

```
int (*pt2Function)(float, char, char) = NULL;   

if (pt2Function)
    pt2Function(5.0f, 'a', 'b');


 NSArray* array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a",@"b", nil];



void(^enumerateBlock)(id,NSUInteger,BOOL*) = ^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    // some code
};

[array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:enumerateBlock];

// OR

[array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
   // inline block 
}];

// using a typedef for code neatness

typedef void(^typedefBlockVar)(id,NSUInteger,BOOL*);

typedefBlockVar myEnumrateBlock = ^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    // some code
};

[array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:myEnumrateBlock];
```